# relative path to file in the outer outer folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

say Im currently at
`/src/components/SideBar/SideBar.js`
there is `App.js` inside `/src`,
I want to import a module from `App.js` to `SideBar.js`,
I dont know how to define the path,
`".../App.js"`doenst work

Comment: Have you tried "../../App.js"?

Answer (score 0):

Go back 2 directories
`"../../App.js"`